# Updating PartialView mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, viewbag

Ey!
How I could refresh a Partial View with data out of the Model?
First time, when the page loads it's working properly, but not when I call it from the Action.
The structure I've created looks like:

Anywhere in my View:

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdatePoints");}
```

My PartialView "UpdatePoints":

```
<h3>Your points are @ViewBag.points </h3>
```

At the Controller I have:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePoints()
        {

            ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points;
            return PartialView("UpdatePoints");
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for your help! Finally I used JQuery/AJAX as you suggested, passing the parameter using model.

So, in JS:

```
$('#divPoints').load('/Schedule/UpdatePoints', UpdatePointsAction);
var points= $('#newpoints').val();
$element.find('PointsDiv').html("You have" + points+ " points");
```

In Controller:

```
var model = _newPoints;
return PartialView(model);
```

In View

```
<div id="divPoints"></div>
@Html.Hidden("newpoints", Model)
```

Comment: Are you looking to use AJAX for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear, when does it work and when does it not? Show us the code you are using for both

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, say you have your View with PartialView, which have to be updated by button click:

```
<div class="target">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdatePoints");}
</div>

<input class="button" value="update" />
```

There are some ways to do it. For example you may use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $('.button').on("click", function(){        
            $.post('@Url.Action("PostActionToUpdatePoints", "Home")').always(function(){
                $('.target').load('/Home/UpdatePoints');        
            })        
        });
    });        
</script>
```

`PostActionToUpdatePoints` is your `Action` with `[HttpPost]` attribute, which you use to update points

If you use logic in your action UpdatePoints() to update points, maybe you forgot to add [HttpPost] attribute to it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePoints()
{    
    ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points;
    return PartialView("UpdatePoints");
}
```

Comment: guys, this solution works. few repairs though. If you put HttpPost annotation you will not be able to do the Get through jquery load function. remove the annotation.  the "Load" function is lowercase. and the post method is "$.post" instead od $post. fix this little things and it will work like a charm

Comment: this line resolve me several hours of failures $('.target').load('/Home/UpdatePoints'); Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 9):

You can also try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        setInterval(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        }, 30000); //Refreshes every 30 seconds

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //Turn off caching
    });
```

It makes an initial call to load the div, and then subsequent calls are on a 30 second interval.

In the controller section you can update the object and pass the object to the partial view.

```
public class ControllerName: Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        .
        .   // code for update object
        .
        return PartialView("PartialViewName", updatedObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks all for your help!
Finally I used JQuery/AJAX as you suggested, passing the parameter using model.

So, in JS:

```
$('#divPoints').load('/Schedule/UpdatePoints', UpdatePointsAction);
var points= $('#newpoints').val();
$element.find('PointsDiv').html("You have" + points+ " points");
```

In Controller:

```
var model = _newPoints;
return PartialView(model);
```

In View

```
<div id="divPoints"></div>
@Html.Hidden("newpoints", Model)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult Refresh(string ID)
    {
        DetailsViewModel vm = new DetailsViewModel();  // Model
        vm.productDetails = _product.GetproductDetails(ID); 
        /* "productDetails " is a property in "DetailsViewModel"
        "GetProductDetails" is a method in "Product" class
        "_product" is an interface of "Product" class */

        return PartialView("_Details", vm); // Details is a partial view
    }
```

**In yore index page you should to have refresh link :**

```
     <a href="#" id="refreshItem">Refresh</a>
```

**This Script should be also in your index page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
    $('a[id=refreshItem]:last').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = MVC.Url.action('Refresh', 'MyController', { itemId: '@(Model.itemProp.itemId )' }); // Refresh is an Action in controller, MyController is a controller name

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function (grid) {
                $('#tabItemDetails').html(grid);
                clientBehaviors.applyPlugins($("#tabProductDetails")); // "tabProductDetails" is an id of div in your "Details partial view"
            }
        });
    });
});
```