# reload partial view Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a a partial view "_search" that display a list of data I added a textbox for search and a link search

when I click on the link I get an error page undefined. how can I execute the search method and display th same partial view 
 in my search method I return json

```
        return Json(
        {
            Data = base.RenderPartialView("_search", model),
                        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

search view 
I changed `<a>` with a button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Search")'
    };
</script>

<button id="myButton" >search</button>
```

Comment: Why are you returning `Partial View` in `json result` ?.

Comment: what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Where is your code for the  click event ? How are you calling this action method  and finally your current code is not returning partial view!

Comment: You just `return PartialView("_search", model)`. However, you are not making an AJAX call -- you are telling the browser to navigate away. Full example in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p/19410973#19410973).

Answer (score 2):

You must repair code because you can't return partialview with json type and .... The best way that i suggest you, before send question searched in google website that how to implement this task.

The following link help you to understand how to implement this work:

https://www.google.com/search?q=reload+partial+in+mvc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

also you can see the example of how to ' Auto Refresh Partial View in ASP.NET MVC ' in the following link:

https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1132/auto-refresh-partial-view-in-asp-dot-net-mvc

**Example**:

So, say you have your View with PartialView, which have to be updated by button click:

```
<div class="target">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdatePoints");}
</div>
<input class="button" value="update" />
```

There are some ways to do it. For example you may use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $('.button')click(function(){        
            $.post('@Url.Action("PostActionToUpdatePoints", "Home")').always(function(){
                $('.traget').Load('/Home/UpdatePoints');        
            })        
        });
    });        
</script>
```

PostActionToUpdatePoints is your Action with [HttpPost] attribute, which you use to update points

If you use logic in your action UpdatePoints() to update points, maybe you forgot to add [HttpPost] attribute to it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePoints()
{    
    ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points;
    return PartialView("UpdatePoints");
}
```

I hope this help you.

**Reference:**

[Updating PartialView mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254749/updating-partialview-mvc-4)

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for ,I have a view with textbox for search and list of data from the db I need when I click search link to rerfresh the view with result

Comment: ok, i found the sample in my github account: follow following link:https://github.com/omidnasri/RenderPartialView