# Updating a Partial View in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am getting an error when trying to load a partial view that should display a list on the create view of the MVC app. The list is based on a value will come from a list of values drop control.

On create view there is no selection so the list is empty and will need to refreshed after the user selects a value while in the MVC create view.

I followed the accepted answer on this question and got errors:

[Updating PartialView mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254749/updating-partialview-mvc-4)

But I have some questions about what is being said.

Someone said: "There are some ways to do it. For example you may use jQuery:" and he shows the Java query.

But he also shows another method and says: "If you use logic in your action UpdatePoints() to update points"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePoints()
{    
   ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points;
   return PartialView("UpdatePoints");
 }
```

I get the following error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateList(Int32)' in 'System.Controllers.RController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I have no clue what this error means

So in create view:

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="form-horizontal" style="display:none" id="PVList">

                @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdateList");}

            </div>
        </div>
```

In controller under the create action as its own function

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateList(int ID)
    {

        if (ID != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.List = Get_List(ID);
            return PartialView("PV_List");

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.List = "";
            return PartialView("");
        }


    }
```

And the function that makes the list for the view bag function:

```
private List<SQL_VIEW_LIST> Get_List(int ID)
        {

            return db.SQL_VIEW_LIST.Where(i => i.ID == ID).ToList();
        }
```

The JavaScript for the for the list of values drop down list of values: That also controls turning on the visibility of the list when it has data:

```
    //Fire The List to make visible after list values select 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#RES_VEH_ID').change(function ()
        {

            $("#PV_List").show(); // Shows Edit Message
            $.post('@Url.Action("PostActionTo_Partial","Create")').always(function()
                   { ('.target').load('/Create'); })

        });
    })
```

Also does anyone know what this string mean: ? "PostActionTo_Partial"

Also does anyone know what this means ViewBag.points =  _Repository.Points; I get the view bag part but it's the  _Repository.Points; part that I don't understand. Any one have any ideas of what is going on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what do you try to do. But i'll try to answer.

> I have no clue what this error means.

This error means that model binder can't find parameter "ID" for action method

```
public ActionResult UpdateList(int ID)
```

Because you don't send any parameter for this method:
You can try this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("UpdateList", new {ID="value"});}
```

Or you can set default value in your method:

```
public ActionResult UpdateList(int ID=value)
```

or make "ID" nullable:

```
public ActionResult UpdateList(int? ID)
```

> Also does anyone know what this string mean: ? "PostActionTo_Partial"

this is "action name" in yor controller

> Also does anyone know what this means ViewBag.points =
>   _Repository.Points;

it means assigning dynamic object "VivBag.points' data to transfer them into view

Comment: Hello And thank you for the help. What I was trying to was to update a partial view that is on the create view when a drop down is selected. So if you think of webforms when a user clicks a value in the drop down you could update a list control with some values based on that selection. I was hoping the same thing could be done with the mvc application. The answer on the other thread was very confusing because it did not show what happens if the list is empty or updated. So I may be blending to ways of doing the same thing. Also if the id need to be from a drop down how would it be referenced?

Comment: Ok thanks from the viewbag info so this user must have something more complex going on regarding how he got is viewbag data to make it the partialview work with a dot(.) something... Do you know of an easy way to udpate a partial view? I am currently reading this https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/tips-and-tricks-about-razor-partial-views/ but it just so technical... I am having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: OK.Edit your question and show your full code of "create view" and where is your "dropdown list", and show your partial views "UpdatePoints" and "UpdateList". I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi @Konstantine Zikevich... My dropdown is not the problem... it is the partial view thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

So with help from Matt Bodily You can Populate a Partial View  in the create view triggered by a changed value in a drop down list using a view

bag and something called Ajax. Here is how I made my code work.

First the partial view code sample you need to check for null data

_WidgetListPartial

```
 @if (@ViewBag.AList != null)
    {
    <table cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Widget Name 
        </th>
     </tr>

@foreach (MvcProgramX.Models.LIST_FULL item in @ViewBag.AList)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.WidgetName
        </td>        
    </tr>
   }

   </table>
  }
```

Populating your View Bag in your controller with a function

```
    private List<DB_LIST_FULL> Get_List(int? VID)
    {

        return db.DB_LIST_FULL.Where(i => i.A_ID == VID).ToList();
    }
```

In your Create controller add a structure like this using the [HttpGet] element
this will send you data and your partial view to the screen placeholder you have on your create screen The VID will be the ID from your Drop

down list this function also sends back the Partial View back to the create form screen

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdatePartialViewList(int? VID)
    {           

        ViewBag.AList = Get_List(VID);
        return PartialView("_WidgetListPartial",ViewBag.AList);


    }
```

I am not 100% if this is needed but I added to the the following to the ActionResult  Create the form Id and the FormCollection so that I could

read the value from the drop down. Again the Ajax stuff may be taking care if it  but just in case and the application seems to be working with

it.

This is in the [HttpPost]

```
   public ActionResult Create(int RES_VID, FormCollection Collection, [Bind(Include = "... other form fields
```

This is in the [HttpGet] again this too may not be needed. This is reading a value from the form

```
 UpdatePartialViewList(int.Parse(Collection["RES_VID"]));
```

On Your Create View Screen where you want your partial view to display

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="form-horizontal" style="display:none" id="PV_WidgetList">

                @{ Html.RenderAction("UpdatePartialViewList");}



            </div>
        </div>
```

And finally the Ajax code behind that reads the click from the dropdown list. get the value of the selected item and passed the values back to

all of the controller code behind to build the list and send it to update the partial view   and if there is data there it pass the partial view

with the update list to the create form.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#RES_VID').change(function ()
        {

            debugger;

            $.ajax(

                {
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePartialViewList")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { VID: $('#RES_VID').val() },

                    success: function (partialView)
                    {
                        $('#PV_WidgetList').html(partialView);
                        $('#PV_WidgetList').show();
                    }
                });
```

This many not be the best way to do it but this a a complete an tested answer as it work and it is every step of the process in hopes that no

one else has to go through the multi-day horror show I had to go through to get something that worked as initially based on the errors I thought

this could not be done in mvc and I would have to continue the app in webforms instead. Thanks again to everyone that helped me formulate this

solution!